# Error compiling SPM12 for MATLAB on a Mac M1 with Big Sur

Tags: macos, matlab, apple-m1, matlab-spm

I have some problems, trying to install SPM12 on my Mac M1 with Big Sur. My config is:

- Mac M1 Big Sur (11.3.1) - 512/16GB
- MATLAB_R2020a
- SPM12

I followed the instruction [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPM/Installation_on_64bit_Mac_OS_(Intel)#SPM12)

1. On Matlab: `addpath ./Downloads/spm12/; savepath`
2. On Terminal: `export PATH=/Applications/MATLAB_R2020a.app/bin:$PATH`
3. On Terminal (for allowing mex file): `sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine ./Downloads/spm12/`
4. On Terminal `sudo find ./Downloads/spm12/ -name \*.mexmaci64 -exec spctl --add {} \;`
5. On Terminal (spm12/src): `make distclean`
6. On Terminal (spm12/src): `make && make install` and it crashes there:

```
mc@MCs-MacBook-Air src % make && make install
_____________________________________________________________

         MacOS compilation (Intel 64 bit)
_____________________________________________________________

mex -O -largeArrayDims -c spm_vol_utils.c -DSPM_UNSIGNED_CHAR 

    Sorry! We could not determine the machine architecture
           for your host. Please contact:

               MathWorks Technical Support

           for further assistance.

/Applications/MATLAB_R2020a.app/bin/mex: line 295: cleanup: command not found
make: *** [utils_uchar.mexmaci64.o] Error 1
```

How can I get SPM12 to build?

Comment: It says "Please contact: MathWorks Technical Support for further assistance." Did you do this?

Comment: Also, the instructions you link say that pre-build MEX-files come with the distribution, you don't need to build them yourself. The section under "Compilation" is not necessary to do, only if you modify the source code.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I haven't contacted them, as I thought it might be a "common error" that I was not aware of. To be honest I am pretty new in this field, and I am only following benches of tutorials. 

What do you mean by I don't need to build them myself? As I don't want to modify the source code, maybe only to make it run in silicon puce

Answer (score 0):

Got it! So as you said I shouldn't have done the compilation. As I am with Big Sure I only needed to do:

```
sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine SPM_PATH
sudo find SPM_PATH -name \*.mexmaci64 -exec spctl --add {} \;
```

Thanks for your help ;)