# Error with Mex files using SPM12 on Apple M1 Sonoma

Tags: matlab

I am unable to run SPM12 on MacOS Sonoma. When I try to launch SPM, I get the following:

```
>> spm
Error using spm_check_installation>check_basic
SPM uses a number of MEX files, which are compiled functions.
These need to be compiled for the various platforms on which SPM
is run. It seems that the compiled files for your computer platform
are missing or not compatible. See
   https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPM/Installation_on_64bit_Mac_OS_(Intel)
for information about how to compile MEX files for MACA64
in MATLAB 23.2.0.2391609 (R2023b) Update 2.

Error in spm_check_installation (line 28)
        check_basic;

Error in spm (line 290)
spm_check_installation('basic');
```

Here is my setup:

- Mac M1 Sonoma
- MATLAB_R2023b
- SPM12

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69408241/error-compiling-spm12-for-matlab-on-a-mac-m1-with-big-sur) is for the same problem, but the solution does not work for me. This [answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/2037676-i-am-trying-to-run-spm12-with-matlab-2023b-on-my-macos-but-i-got-this-error-when-i-type-spm-and-i) does not work, either.

Comment: You need to compile the MEX-files. They are likely not pre-compiled for M1 Macs, since MATLAB has only supported  these chips since very recently. You're on R2023b, so presumably you're running MATLAB in native mode, not through Rosetta like you would have done with older versions of MATLAB. That means that the MEX-files will have an extension `.mexmaca64`, rather than `. mexmaci64` you used on Intel Macs.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks, that's correct, I'm not using Rosetta. What is the correct way to compile the MEX files? I tried the instructions here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPM/Installation_on_64bit_Mac_OS_(Intel) but it did not work

Comment: If you don’t have the XCode command-line tools, do `xcode-select –install` in a terminal window. Next, follow the directions on that web page: `export PATH=/Applications/MATLAB_R2023b.app/bin:$PATH`, and then the longer list of commands `make distclean`, `make && make install` etc.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you — I ran those instructions but now I get the following error when trying to use spm: 
"Error using spm_platform>init_platform
MACA64 not supported architecture for SPM12

Error in spm_platform (line 61)
if isempty(PLATFORM), PLATFORM = init_platform; end

Error in spm_Welcome (line 22)
PF = spm_platform('fonts');

Error in spm (line 299)
spm_Welcome;"

Comment: It seems like this SPM12 specifically forbids my architecture: https://github.com/neurodebian/spm12/blob/b86f0712da80daa4fae7939eeebebe0b2629cbc0/spm_platform.m#L151

Comment: It seems I have "arm64"

Comment: Yes, M1 is arm64 chip. Try to make simple mex following https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html

Comment: That file hasn’t been changed in 9 years. It is not specifically forbidding your architecture, it just does not know it exists. You could edit that file to add your architecture, then submit it as a PR to their repo so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thanks all, I really was spinning my wheels unnecessarily trying to compile the MEX files

Comment: The description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69408241/error-compiling-spm12-for-matlab-on-a-mac-m1-with-big-sur) works for me on MacOS Sonoma M2